# Getting empty CSV while converting XML to CSV

Tags: xml, python-3.x, csv

I've a CSV as given below. I'm trying to convert it to CSV and then from CSV to `tfrecord` for training a model in `TensorFlow`.

```
<annotation>
    <folder>imgs</folder>
    <filename>steve_jobs.jpg</filename>
    <path>C:/Users/kulkaa/PythonProjects/tensor_android/imgs/steve_jobs.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>183</width>
        <height>276</height>
        <depth>3</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>steve_jobs</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>8</xmin>
            <ymin>13</ymin>
            <xmax>178</xmax>
            <ymax>227</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

I wrote a `python` program to convert that `XML` to `CSV`. I even created an empty directory named as `data`.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/*.xml'):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for member in root.findall('object'):
            value = (root.find('filename').text,
                     int(root.find('size')[0].text),
                     int(root.find('size')[1].text),
                     member[0].text,
                     int(member[4][0].text),
                     int(member[4][1].text),
                     int(member[4][2].text),
                     int(member[4][3].text)
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)
    column_name = ['filename', 'width', 'height', 'class', 'xmin', 'ymin', 'xmax', 'ymax']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns=column_name)
    return xml_df


def main():
    for directory in ['train','test']:
        image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'imgs/{}'.format(directory))
        if image_path is None:
            print('Error!')
        xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
        #Storing the csv file into the data directory.
        xml_df.to_csv('data/{}.csv'.format(directory), index=None)
        print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')

main()
```

When I run it in Spyder, it gets compiled successfully, but converted CSV is always empty as shown in below image...
[image: CSV]
How can I fix it?

Comment: anyone here who can answer this question?

Comment: sometimes your path of image is different.make sure that you have train & test folder inside images  . reserch/object_detection/training/images-train & test folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your def main function to:

```js
def main():
    for folder in ['train','test']:
        image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), ('images/' + folder))
        xml_df = xml_to_csv(image_path)
        xml_df.to_csv(('images/' + folder + '_labels.csv'), index=None)
        print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')
```